# How do I correct this friend template function link error, implemented in .cpp file?

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I would like to implement an `Array<T>` template class. I defined the class, overloaded `operator << ()` operator function for printing. Thinks seems not hard.

However, when implementing subtraction by overloading `operator - ()` for two Array object, there is link error.

Both the `operator << ()` and `operator - ()` are declared in `array.h`, declared as `friend` in Array class, implemented in `Array.cpp`, and "declared with specified double type"(I don't really know the correct phrase to describe it..).

Here's the code:
`array.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef MY_ARRAY_H
#define MY_ARRAY_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Array;

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Array<T>& mat);

template<class T>
Array<T> operator - (const Array<T>& A, const Array<T>& B);

template<class T>
class Array {
public:
    Array(): len(0), data(NULL) {}
    Array(int _len): len(_len), data(new T[len]) {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            data[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    Array(const Array& arr) = delete;
    const Array& operator = (const Array&) = delete;
    ~Array() {
        if (!data) delete[] data;
    }

public:
    int len;
    T* data;

private:
    friend std::ostream& operator << <T>(std::ostream& os, const Array<T>& arr);
    friend Array<T> operator - <T>(const Array<T>& A, const Array<T>& B);
};


#endif // MY_ARRAY
```

`array.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Array<T>& arr)
{
    for (int i=0; i<arr.len; i++) {
        os << arr.data[i] << ", ";
    }
    os << "\n";
    return os;
}


// T=double
template
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Array<double>& arr);




template<class T>
Array<T> operator - (const Array<T>& A, const Array<T>& B)
{
    assert(A.len==B.len && "dimension mismatch(rows)");

    Array<T> C(A.rows, A.cols);
    for (int i=0; i<C.len; i++) {
        C.data[i] = A.data[i] - B.data[i];
    }

    return C;
}

// // T=double
Array<double> operator - (const Array<double>& A, const Array<double>& B);
```

`array_test.cpp`

```cpp
#include "array.h"


int main()
{
    Array<double> arr(4);
    for (int i=0; i<arr.len; i++) {
        arr.data[i] = i;
    }
    
    std::cout << arr << std::endl;

    Array<double> arr2(4);
    for (int i=0; i<arr2.len; i++) {
        arr2.data[i] = 1;
    }

    std::cout << (arr2-arr) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To compile:

```
clang++ array.cpp array_test.cpp
```

Suffers link error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/array_test-c0515e.o: in function `main':
array_test.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `Array<double> operator-<double>(Array<double> const&, Array<double> const&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I change my code, to solve this link error?

Comment: For templates, method definitions should be inline.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Check your `operator-`. Explicit instantiation should start with a `template` keyword.